# Java Scheduler Thread Switching

Tags: java, threadpool, scheduler

I've read somewhere that in Java scheduler, thread switching happens after execution of certain amount of instructions and not after a certain time (like schedulers used in operating systems). But the references were missing. I wanted to know if this is correct.

Comment: The documentation for the core scheduler implementation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). You didn't mention which impl you are using

Comment: @Lance Java: It was not mentioned in the article that I read. I want to know if this is the case in any version of Java-ME or Java-SE

Comment: There's only two schedulers that I've ever encountered in my career. [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) (a 3rd party library) and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor (part of the core java API since java 1.4). It's impossible to discuss implementation details until you know which one you're talking about.

Comment: @Lance Java: I want to know about the Java core thread scheduler. In the link of your previous comment, It does not explain the detail implementations of Java scheduler itself. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Care to share the article you're referring to?

Comment: There hasn't been any such thing as a Java scheduler that does thread switching for nearly all of this century.

Comment: @dimo414: Sorry but I can't

Comment: @Arvin In that case your question is pointless. You are citing an article that must be at least 15 years out of date and you won't even tell us what it is or what it actually says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java used to have a feature called [GreenThreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads), It was removed in 1.3. For all practical purposes we can assume that thread scheduling is directly influenced by the underlying operating systems's process/thread scheduling strategy. In this context, developers need to assume that threads are executed/scheduled randomly and should code/treat them as such.

Comment: I know. My question is that in Java when a thread is selected to be executed, it will run for a certain amount of time or for a certain number of instructions?

Comment: @Arvin Your question is about something that doesn't exist: a Java thread scheduler. Thread scheduling is done by the operating system, not by Java, and it certainly isn't done based on numbers of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the scheduling of Java threads is done using the Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS). For each CPU there is a run-queue and by default there is 24 ms in which all threads on a single-run queue should have a chance to run. So if there are 2 threads, each thread gets 12 ms, if there are 3 tasks, each thread gets 8 ms.

When tasks have a different priority, things chance. And also there is a minimum granularity to prevent reduce context switching overhead of many threads are running.